# javascript best algorithm for min() with 2 or more arguments?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, min

I am wondering what is the best possible algorithm in JS for a min() function with two or more arguments ?

NOTE: it should work on any JS types that can be compared with ">" or "<" operators. For example:

```
   min( new Date(1959,6,3), new Date(1960,7,8), new Date(1925,6,9));
   /*
     should return: Thu Jul 9 00:00:00 UTC+0200 1925
   */
```

Thus Math.min and Math.max might not be the good candidates.

Thanks ...

EDIT: I am thinking along these lines:

```
   "use strict" ;
   var  d1 = new Date(1959,6,3), d2 = new Date(1960,7,8), d3 = new Date(1925,6,9) ;

   function min (a,b)
   {
    if ( arguments.length > 2 ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0) ;
           args.shift() ;
              args[0] = min(a,b) ;
       return min.apply( this, args ) ;     
    }
    else {
            return a > b ? b : a ;
    }
   }
    min(d1,d2,d3);
   /*
    returns: Thu Jul 9 00:00:00 UTC+0200 1925
   */
```

Above can be optimized, but it works for 2 or more numbers and strings too. Of course inside JS intrinsic comparators rules.

Comment: you can compare timestamps

Comment: [`_.min()`](http://underscorejs.org/#min), especially [lodash's version](http://lodash.com/docs#min), should work well for this.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski :: I know.

Answer (score 2):

watch this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnBbL/):

```
function min(/*...args...*/){
    var len = arguments.length;

    if(len < 1)
        return null;

    var lowest = arguments[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(arguments[i] < lowest)
            lowest = arguments[i];
    }

    return lowest;
}
```

the only thing is (and you should change it as needed) is that if no arguments are passed it will return `NULL`.  THe Function can take as much arguments as you want.

Comment: please see the linked fiddle. (It is only tested in FF and Chrome, but it is working) http://jsfiddle.net/fnBbL/

Answer (score 1):

i think the `Min()` is ok

From W3schools :

**Return the number with the lowest value:**

```
var a=Math.min(5,10);
var b=Math.min(0,150,30,20,38);
var c=Math.min(-5,10);
var d=Math.min(-5,-10);
var e=Math.min(1.5,2.5);
```

**The result of a,b,c,d, and e will be:**

```
5
0
-5
-10
1.5
```

Comment: -1 : question clearly states : it should work on any JS types that can be compared with ">" or "<" operators.

Comment: @supernova how does it make it difference to what source you are referring as long as the information presented there are true?

Comment: @basilikum: Referencing a source that is known to be erratic does not make a credible reference, but lends credibility to that source.  It is a lose-lose.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is the optimal solution:

```
   "use strict"
    var arr = create_array_of_any_scalar_type_for_testing();
    var min = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {return a < b ? a : b ; });
```

I also dare to think, on all modern browsers this will be the fastest solution, too.
The complete packaged solution might be this:

```
   "use strict" ;

   function min (a,b)
   {
    if ( arguments.length > 2 ) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0) ;
        return args.reduce(function(a, b) {return a < b ? a : b ; });
    }
    else {
            return a > b ? b : a ;
    }
   }  

   /* quick test with dates */
   var  d1 = new Date(1959,6,3), d2 = new Date(1960,7,8), d3 = new Date(1925,6,9) ;

    min(d1,d2,d3);
   /*
    returns: Thu Jul 9 00:00:00 UTC+0200 1925
   */
```

Enjoy .